# set html file as "homepage" in Reactjs

Tags: html, reactjs

Ok I have a react app and I also have HTML(home.html). What I want is to set home.html as homepage, and when someone clicks on the login button to be taken to a react app.
I have tried to edit the "homepage" in the package.json file, but I am getting an error :

> npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL
>
> npm ERR! Could not install from "home.html" as it does not contain a
> package.json file.

Is there some other way to accomplish this?

Comment: You shouldn't need to edit the `package.json` for this. Simply set up two HTML files, one being the `home.html`, and the other, say, `app.html`.Add the login button to the former, and make it redirect the user to the latter. Then start up the react app from there.

Comment: I have done that, but I don't know how to set so when someone goes to my site it opens home.html first. it's always open a react app first.